# cannot get draggable working

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to implement something very similiar to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wkKfB/15/)

However I am using a `table` (`dataTable()`) instead of the `div` they are using.

Its seems though that the method which packs the data into the object being passed to the `drop` container/callback cannot find any of my `external-event` classes

So that in my `drop` callback I end up with an `undefined` `eventObject`

```
function populateWorkOrders(){

var workOrdersTableBody = document.getElementById("workOrdersTableBody");//Link to the containing element using getElementById or similar

for (i=0;i<workOrders.length;i++) { //Loops for the length of the list

    var tr=document.createElement('tr'); //Creates <ul> element
    tr.setAttribute("class","external-event");
    tr.setAttribute("draggable","true");


    var workOrderId=document.createElement('td'); //Chrome seems not to like the variable "name" in this instance
    workOrderId.innerHTML=workOrders[i].workOrderId; //Adds name
    tr.appendChild(workOrderId);

    var workOrderTitle=document.createElement('td');
    workOrderTitle.innerHTML=workOrders[i].workOrderTitle;
    tr.appendChild(workOrderTitle);

    var workOrderAccount=document.createElement('td');
    workOrderAccount.innerHTML=workOrders[i].workOrderAccount;
    tr.appendChild(workOrderAccount);

    var workOrderPriority=document.createElement('td');
    workOrderPriority.innerHTML=workOrders[i].workOrderPriority;
    tr.appendChild(workOrderPriority);

    workOrdersTableBody.appendChild(tr);
}
  //THIS IS WHATS NOT RUNNING AND IT SEEMS THAT IT CANT FIND ANYTHING
$('#external-events tr.external-event').each(function() {

        var eventObject = {
            title: "fulltitle"//$.trim($(this).data) // use the element's text as the event title
        };

        // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
        $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

        // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
        $(this).draggable({
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
            revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
        });

    });


$('#workOrdersTable').dataTable();
```

}

This ends up producing this
[image]

It seems to append "odd" and "even" to the class name.  To get rid of that I can surround (under the table) everything in a `div` tag but then that breaks `DataTables()` and still doesnt fix the issue .

Here is the html:

```
    <title>TITLE</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/indexJs.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <!--had to load this separate from full calender lib else there were conflicts-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <table class="display" id="workOrdersTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Account</th>
                    <th>Priority</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="workOrdersTableBody">
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script>
        populateWorkOrders();
    </script>
    <br>
    <div>
        <select id="technicianServiceTeamSelectorDropDown"  style="width:25%"  onchange="populateTechnicians();"></select>
        <br>
        <select id="technicianSelectorDropDown" style="display:none; width:25%" onchange="populateCalendar()"></select>
        <script>
                populateTechniciansServiceTeams();
        </script>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id='calendar'>
        <!--had to load this separate from data tables lib else there were conflicts-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src='js/libs/fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='js/libs/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='js/libs/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
    </div>
</body>
```

So the above shows the draggable elements.  Here is the code for the drop.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: false,
        droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
        drop: function(date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

            // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
            var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
            console.log(originalEventObject);
            // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
            var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

            // assign it the date that was reported
            //copiedEventObject.title = "h";
            copiedEventObject.start = date;
            copiedEventObject.allDay = true;

            // render the event on the calendar
            // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

        }
    }); });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There where 2 issues preventing this from working

adding jquery-ui

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jqueryui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

and changing the each to just tr.external-event

```
$('tr.external-event').each(function() {
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, first off, I don't see an id="external-events" anywhere  on the image you provided so I'm not sure where the bind is set to.  Did you change the id name at some point during development?

Second, when I've done stuff like this in the past, what I found to be the easiest was to just create a string with the actual html code in it like as follows:

```
    var html = '<td id="' + theId + '" class="' + theClass + '" >' + someText + '</td>';
```

Then at the end use jquery .append() or .html() depending on exactly what was happening:

```
    $('#myTable').append(html);
```

I don't know if that helps you but I've had a lot of success with that method.

For setting up the draggable events, there are a few options:  You can use jQuery's draggable if that is what you need.  I've also done it all manually before, using a .on('mousedown'.....) to start the event, then a .on('mousemove', ...) to change the left attribute, and then a .on('mouseup', ...) to end it.  This worked much better for me when the dragable was more complex.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried to put a <div id="external-events"> between <tbody> and <tr>.  however this breaks dataTables and also doesnt fix the error.  but it does remove the "odd" and "even" words that are appended to the "external-event".  but regardless like i said it didnt fix anything it terms of that section of code running.

Comment: If there is nothing with an id="external-events" then this jquery ``$('#external-events tr.external-event') will not return anything.  That selector is looking for a row with class="external-event" INSIDE of something with an id="external-events".  If no such id exists then the jquery selector return an empty array so the .each loop never runs.  Where in the DOM does this drag even start?

Comment: I added more code which i hope answers your question.  like i said, I have tested with a <div id="external-events"> after <tbody> and surrounding "tr.external-event" but the results did not change, it did not find the elements and the eventObject is always undefined.

Comment: The DOM won't allow/recognize a div inside of a tbody in that way.  Where is the drag starting?  It looks like it ends in <tbody id="workOrdersTableBody"  but I dont see where it starts.    As a side note, the odd/even class is just part of dataTable package adding every other row background coloring.  I think there is a setting for turning that off, applied when you first delcare the table.  Or you could force it with $('.odd, .even').removeClass('odd').removeClass('even');

Comment: I have done a remove but it didnt change anything.   im pretty sure that since there is a space there is becomes 2 class names and "external-event" still gets read as a single class.  im not sure what you mean by "where is the drag starting"  my first section of code has where the tr is set to draggable true and the .each function which packs the data into all of them.

Comment: I looked closer and both your code and the example you showed.  Change ``$('#external-events tr.external-event').each(....  to ``$('#workOrdersTableBody tr.external-event').each(.... and give that a try.  If that doesn't work then it may be possible that this particular kind of event is not compatible with the dataTable package.  I've played with dataTable before and run into a similar situatin.  It (dataTable) works great as it is but certain things you add to it really mess things up.